# how to convert solr date math to java datetime

Tags: date, solr, lucene

My solr date range looks like this:

```
date:[NOW/MONTH-1MONTH TO NOW/MONTH]
```

Is there a way i can convert this to get Java dattime

e.g the above can be translated to

`date:[01-05-2017 00 00 00 TO 02-05-2017 12 00 15]`

or something like that.

**EDIT:Here is my use case**

So i have api to which i can send the date like this

`date:[NOW/MONTH-1MONTH TO NOW/MONTH]`.

Which then talks to solr and get the results for last one month in this case. But the individual results will have date in epoch time, which will be in the range of the last 1 month if the api is behaving correctly.

I am trying to write some automation to check the integrity of the result set.

So somehow i have to figure out that the all the results that i got from the api  for the query `date:[NOW/MONTH-1MONTH TO NOW/MONTH]` have dates within this last month range ?

In summary i need to figure out if the epoch time for individual documents returned by the api is within the date range that i asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what you mean. NOW, MONTH etc are Solr provided facilities so you don't have to provide plain dates in the [format Solr requires](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT).

If you want to provide the low level dates yourself, sure, it is easy in Java:

1. get the Date object you need to express
2. format it in the right [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT)

If you haven't already, you should check out [relevant docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates)

EDIT: well then I think they issue has little to do with Solr...you just need to store NOW's date value in the exact instant you send the query to Solr, and then verify all dates returned based off that value, no?

Comment: perhaps i should be more clear in explaining my use case. Please see the edit to the question.

Comment: seems like i have to write that custom logic .which i was trying to avoid.